# cordova angularjs and console.log in xCode

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, angularjs, cordova

This one drives me a little crazy... :)

I'm building a Cordova-app for iOS, using angularjs for the app-logic.

Now, when the app receives a device-ready message, console.log works from that point on.
But I want to observe some variables during the initialization process, for example in the `angular.module('..'[...]).config(function(...)){ [...]});` - this doesn't work, though. If I put a `console.log` into these parts of the JS, I don't get any console.log outputs in xCode.

How do I debug the angular initialization process when I can't see the log-messages?

Comment: Can you not just run it in the browser to do the debugging?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I need to run some functionality (push) that's only available on the device...

Answer (score 0):

You can do the angular initialization after deviceready event. You can call angular.bootstrap in order to achieve this.